# ios NSFetchRequest for two related tables

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

my program has a sqlite database with two related tables. One called "Rank" and other one called "Requirement"

I want to fetch all rows from the "Requirement" table that has a relationship with the specific row in a "Rank" table. Following is my code, it grabs the whole table, but I get the specified rows only according to the above mentioned rule.

```
-(NSArray *) getAllRequirementsForTheRank:(Rank *) rank
{
    NSError *error;

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init]autorelease];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Requirement" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];   

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *searchType = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Rank = %@", rank];

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:searchType];


    NSArray *scoutRequirementArray  = [self.context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]; 

    for (Requirement *r in scoutRequirementArray)
    {
        NSLog(@"Requirementttt : %@ :", r.requirementName);
    }

    return scoutRequirementArray;       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the relationship modelled in core data, just get the linked objects from the relationship property. You don't need another fetch request. `rank.requirements` will give you an NSSet of everything you need. (I'm assuming names for your object and properties here).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just managed to get it working by adding "NSPredicate *searchType = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"rank = %@", rank];
 
 [fetchRequest setPredicate:searchType];"

Comment: That would work, but it's slower and a lot more code than you need.